# How to use _one_ shell globbing expression to list all files (of course hidden files too!)?

Tags: shell, globbing

Ok, this question targets Unix/Linux shells!

I want a shell globbing (aka wildcard) pattern or GLOBIGNORE list that matches all files, *including* hidden files, in the current directory non-recursively (maxdepth == 1). So far, I have to perform two commands or use long workarounds (see below):

```
ls -lad *vim*
ls -lad .*vim*
```

while using zsh. If I remember, it's the same for dash and bash, right?

Short workarounds:

```
ls -la | grep vim
find . -maxdepth 1 | grep vim
```

I've wondered a hundred times: isn't there a simple globbing solution to this? Why does `*` not match the dot character?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### `*` *does* match a `.` character.

It simply doesn't match `.` when it is the first character of the name.  This provides a so-called "dot file" mechanism for "hiding" files.

### In `zsh`:

Set the `GLOB_DOTS` shell option.  This is in § 14.8 of the `zsh` user manual.  Note that `.` and `..` are always excluded even if this option is turned on.

### In `bash`:

Set the `dotglob` shell option.  This is in § 3.5.8 of the `bash` user manual.  Note that setting the `GLOBIGNORE` shell variable implicitly sets `dotglob`; that `bash` (unlike `zsh`) doesn't automatically exclude `.` and `..` when `dotglob` is enabled; but that `bash` *will* do that when `GLOBIGNORE` is set.  So setting `GLOBIGNORE=.` will have the effect of turning on `dotglob` *and* excluding `.` and `..`.

### In GNU `find`:

Don't do anything.  As of `findutils` 4.2.2, the globbing for `-name` and `-iname` *already* matches names with dots as the first character.  This is in § 2.1.1 of the `findutils` user manual.

Comment: BE CAREFUL with this! In Bash .* matches everything including one directory up.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to change any options, any of these will do:

```
ls -ld {,.}*vim*
ls -ld *vim* .*vim*
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*vim*"
```

Comment: why there is a comma in between the braces? Does the `*` also don't match the comma in the front of the file name? The other two I already gave as workarounds.

Comment: @math: in bash you can use things like `{a,b,c}x` → `ax bx cx`, so `{,.}*vim*` expands to two arguments `*vim* .*vim*`

Comment: @math ... {,.} looks funny, I know. It is a list of two items: NOTHING and .

Answer (score 3):

In bash, enable the *dotglob* option:

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

By default, hidden files are hidden to not cause surprises and annoyances – for example, you run `ls` in your home directory, see some files from last month, try to remove them with `rm *net*` and unknowingly nuke your carefully written `.nethackrc`.

Comment: Yes, indeed, enabling it by default is not a good idea!, but fortunately Zsh is able to set and unset options via: `setopt` and `unsetopt`, so I can enable it when I need it more often and disable it afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

In ZSH (without changing GLOB_DOTS) you could do

```
  ls -lad *vim*(D)
```

Answer (score 1):

To build on the answer of @daniel kullman, this seems to accomplish what you want with a fairly simple glob, even though it's not strictly a single gob.

> Recursively search for the string "blah" in all files in the current directory, including hidden files, and excluding the ".." that causes the parent directory structure to be searched:

```
grep blah {,.}[!.]*
```